# MySQL null values in Golang

Tags: mysql, go

How have you solved the issue around `LEFT JOIN`'s and null values with MySQL and Go?

For example I have two tables `order` and `order_item`. All columns have the `not null` attribute. An order can have 0 or more order_items. A simple select, left join query of an order without any order_items fails  `Row.Scan()` because the order_item columns come back as null:

```
SELECT * FROM `order`
LEFT JOIN `order_item` USING (order_id)
WHERE `order`.order_id = '123'
```

I can see three solutions, none that I think are really good:

1. Use `COALESCE`/`IFNULL` => Annoying because my select part of the query is automatically generated.
2. Use the null values from mysql go lib => This will mean that every value in my order_item struct will be of these types.
3. Split the query into 2 => Problem if I want a list of 50 orders with order_items, that will be 51 queries.

Any other solutions you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use option 2 but instead of scanning into your struct and having to change the types of your struct, you can scan into temporary variables with nullable datatypes and based on the validity of those variables, copy their values into your struct with non-nullable types.

Comment: if you feel like it, and you think it's an accurate enough representation of what you meant, you can include [this example](https://play.golang.com/p/XUHkNYDMqbd) in your answer.

Comment: I see what you mean @Wombologist and @mkopriva. One thing though. If I have a custom defined type in the struct that I scan into (ex. `type ItemStatus int32`), does it mean that I would have to create a `NullItemStatus()` function, or can I somehow use something more general?

Comment: @madshov You'll have to define a `NullInt32` that can handle an `int32` type and then use *type conversion* on any custom `int32` types. https://play.golang.com/p/psLdu0kavLB